# Does QGIS use GPU’s to undertake calculations on Windows machine?

Tags: qgis, gpu

I am using SAGA Inverse Distance Weighted to interpolate between 2 large Raster files only it is akin many many hours to do 1 interpolation, let alone the 30 or so interpolations we have to do.

Does QGIS use GPU’s to undertake calculations on Windows machine or not as I am considering using a Cloud Service to try and speed up the process.

Alternatively, does anyone have any suggestions about how to speed up the process?  Please note, while it is interpolation, we are really extrapolating water surfaces.

Comment: Have you tried using the native IDW tool? Might be faster

Comment: Thanks.  We’ll give that a go and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Write a python script that uses the multiprocessing module tp spread across CPUs.I think SAGA is single-processor. Consider using Numba, which can compile GPU code too.

Comment: We’re trying the native tool now.  But it’s still going to take about 15 hours to run.  And with regards to the Python script, how difficult would it be to write?  As you can tell, I’m not a programmer by any means.